# Time dependence of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution

In Griffiths's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, while studying the time evolution of the expectation value of position, the author wrote:
$$\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x|\Psi(x,t)|^2\,dx.$$

So
$$\frac{d\langle x\rangle}{dt}=\int x\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(x,t)|^2\,dx.$$

Did he just assume that $x$ has no time dependence? And why?

Comment: Do you know the difference between the Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures? Just to make sure I aim my answer at the right level :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time derivative of expectation value of position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552695/)

Answer (score 4):

> Did he just assumed that x has no time dependence? And why?

Yes. The outcome of an integral of the form
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,t) \, \text{d}x \tag{1}$$
is a function of time $t$; that is, a function of one real variable (or, loosely speaking, the integral will evaluate to a quantity that will not depend on $x$, only on $t$). Thus, upon differentiating $(1)$, one would get:
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,t) \, \text{d}x = \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \, \text{d}x$$
as dictated by [Leibniz Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) (do note that I've assumed some weak assumptions on the behaviour of $f$, but it is not of incredible interest here). A trivial application of this in
$$\langle x \rangle := \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, |{\Psi(x,t)}|^2 \, \text{d}x$$
yields the desirable result.

Answer (score 2):

The are two formulations of quantum mechanics :

- [**Schrödinger representation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture). The time evolution is encoded in the state vector, wavefunction - $\Psi(x,t)$, and the observables(operators) are constant in time
- [**Heisenberg representation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture). Now the operators evolve in time, and the state vectors are time-independent, kept fixed.

In the case of interacting theories there is a hybrid [**Interaction representation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture). Here the operators evolve with the non-interacting Hamiltonian $H_0$, and the states evolve via the interaction part $H_I$.

So in your case the author uses the Schrödinger representation.

Comment: I suppose strictly speaking in the Schrodinger picture, observables have no *implicit* dependence on time, but they could have explicit time dependence. The OP might find [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310391/157014) and its answers helpful.